# Adding a +1 inside Date function results in an error but when adding +1 outside the Date function the DAX works as intended, why?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

So I've been using the following DAX expression for a while now and today was the first day it caused me problems.

```
Week of Report = DATE(YEAR([Date of Report]), MONTH([Date of Report]), DAY([Date of Report]) - WEEKDAY([Date of Report], 2) + 1)
```

The error I get thrown is:

> MdxScript(Model) (62, 40) Calculation error in measure 'Measure Table'[Week of Report]: An > >argument of function 'DATE' has the wrong data type or the result is too large or too small.

Now after some thought I realized maybe this is a problem with going backwards across a month that I've never noticed. The [Date of Report] was 11/1/2022 and so I figured maybe going backwards to 10/31/22 was causing an issue.

Just for testing purposes I removed the + 1 at the end. The code worked!! It correctly output 10/30/22. So why was that little pesky + 1 causing an issue? I decided to try other variations of DAX that should produce the same output. (I actually ended up adopting one of the alternatives but this question still bugged me enough to post it here)

Code variations that correctly output 10/31/22:

```
Week of Report = DATE(YEAR([Date of Report]), MONTH([Date of Report]), DAY([Date of Report])) - WEEKDAY([Date of Report], 2) + 1
Week of Report = [Date of Report] - WEEKDAY([Date of Report], 2) + 1
```

So why in the world does the first code variation not work?!? Is this a Power BI bug or is there something else at play?

Comment: Can you post a .pbix otherwise this is impossible to debug.

Comment: @David, how do I post a file on StackOverflow. I did not know that was possible. Regardless, the issue can be recreated in an almost empty .pbix. I was able to recreate it simply by creating an empty table in an empty .pbix file and then creating the following two measures: `Date of Report = DATE(2022,11,1)` and week of report as shown in the above question.

Comment: I see now, I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of your formula returns 1

```
DAY([Date of Report])
```

This part of your formula returns 2

```
WEEKDAY([Date of Report], 2)
```

This part of your formula returns 0 (1-2+1)

```
DAY([Date of Report]) - WEEKDAY([Date of Report], 2) + 1
```

You are trying to create a date with a zero day which is why it fails.

Comment: If 0 is not an acceptable input for the day parameter, then why is -1 accepted. When the +1 from the end is removed the formula works but shifts the day backwards two days to 10/20/22 which is correct. Seems like an oversight by Microsoft to allow -1 as a day value but not 0.

Comment: What day would zero equate to in your scenario? Either way, the question seems answered to me.

Comment: I can't edit my comment for whatever reason but -1 should equate to 10/30/22 and 0 should equate to 10/31/22 in my mind. The former is true, the later is not and causes an error. I can edit my question to reflect this but I would like to know why one works and the other does not before I mark an answer as correct.

Comment: The documents explicitly state: "Negative integers are not supported. Valid values are 1-31." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/date-function-dax

Comment: In that case it appears the -1 working is some sort of fluke, I will follow this up on the Microsoft forums. Thanks.